# Is it's possible to have SCOM interrogate Nagios to get the status information of hosts?

Tags: monitoring, nagios, scom

When I said 'like' in the subject, that was just because the English language requires that syntax! I do not like SCOM! But business requirements are almost forcing me to use this as my main pane of glass.

I'd like to know the following:

> Is it's possible to have SCOM interrogate Nagios to get the status
>   information for all the nodes in Nagios, and alert accordingly?

I've done some googling with regards to this, and I came up blank, hence throwing it out to you guys. Feel free to tell me that I'm trying something stupid, or recommend alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

If Nagios is making that information available somewhere (e.g. in logs), SCOM can query it and generate alerts. You may just have to write your own management pack.

Here is a solution that looks promising:
http://www.mbaeker.de/category/tools/scom2nagios/

If that doesn't work for you, then you should read up on management pack authoring so you can write your own rules to collect and display the data from Nagios. Here's a few places to start:

- [Official SCOM MP authoring guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh457564.aspx)

Comment: Since SF wouldn't let me post more than two links: [MPAuthor: the current Microsoft-recommended authoring tool, but it's not mentioned in the above guide!](http://blogs.technet.com/b/momteam/archive/2014/01/13/mp-blog-the-right-tool-for-the-right-job.aspx)